# Can I "squeeze" the x-axis when I solve a diff. eq?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a (rather ugly) differential equation numerically. (If you're curious, the equation is

$\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{\partial_x f(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2+\frac{\partial_x f(x)}{f(x)}\frac{\partial_x v(x)}{v(x)}-\frac{w}{8}v(x)^2=\frac{10^{-12}}{4f(x)^3}$

where $v(k,x)=\frac{Ln\left[4k^3(k+1)\left(\frac{1}{kx}\right)^3+6k^2(k+1)^2\left(\frac{1}{kx}\right)^2+4k(k+1)^3\left(\frac{1}{kx}\right)\right]}{Ln[1/x]}$ and w and k are just numbers ($w,k \sim 1$).)

I know that the solution should have boundaries $f(1)=1$, and that $f(0.6)=0.7$. If I try to numerically solve this from $x_{min}=0.6 \rightarrow x_{max}=1$, mathematica gives division by zero errors.

I tried scaling $x$ so that the equation would go from a different $x_{min}$ to $x_{max}$ to avoid the division by zero. I tried squeezing the x-axis evenly, ($x\rightarrow 0.1x$) and set $f(x_{max})=1$ as a boundary condition. When I try this, I get different results for different compressions (e.g. setting $x\rightarrow 0.1x$ gives different results than $x\rightarrow 0.5x$.

1. Is there a reason why I am not allowed to compress the x-axis in solving a differential equation? (I would think that this should be allowed, I am redefining my variable, and the slope, etc would change, but the overall shape of the plot would be the same, only squeezed.)
2. I can't use both boundary conditions, because than I would be over specifying the system. Am I forced to just accept the boundary values and use this to specify k and w (which I'd prefer to leave as free parameters?

Comment: Nothing should happen since I no longer have $Ln 1$ in my denominator anymore. If I try to solve it from $x_{min}\rightarrow 1$, i get errors. If I try to solve from $x_{min}\rightarrow x_{max} <1$, it solves just fine.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant, you are trying to remove the divide by zero by shifting the axis, right?

Comment: Squeezing (not exactly shifting since I am setting $x\rightarrow bx$, not $x\rightarrow x+b$.)  (i think this would be more accurate to say)

Comment: The problem with that is you have to rescale the Pde by the same transformation. So I don't think you can remove that divide by zero.

Comment: hmmm....that makes sense.
I don't think a shift $x\rightarrow b+x$ would do the trick. 
I tried setting $f(0.99)\approx 1$, but got some solving errors. Would you by chance have any suggestion that comes to mind for numerically solving the original equation?

Comment: I would approach it asymptotically (which is out of my comfort zone for numerical solving pdes) but if I had come across this on my PhD maybe I would look at how you solve numerically pdes when bessel solutions are involved  (not using bessels) since they have an issue with the origin. But it is interesting, if I have some time I would love to code it up ;).